# Visual Studio modifying code when running debugger, replacing == with a space in the middle

Tags: visual-studio, jinja2

Writing a Jinja template as part of a project in visual studio, and every few minutes, everywhere that I have a == b magically changes to a= =b which results in an error, and I have to correct it throughout the file. Why might this happen?